# $_GET not working on specific variable

Tags: php, get

I am working on a php file which gets parameters from a link. Said link is

`http://www.page.com/faltantes.php?filProveedor%5B%5D=Test&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST1&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST11&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST12&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST2&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST3&filEstatus%5B%5D=ST&filEstatus%5B%5D=SC&filPaises%5B%5D=col&aceptar=Aceptar`

There are three parameters which the program needs to get in order to use it in a function: **filProveedor**, **filEstatus**, and **filPaises**.

The first two parameters are being taken without a problem but the third one is not. Here is the code which gets the parameters:

```
if($_GET['cancelar'])
{
    $filProveedor = '';
    $filEstatus = 'SC';
    $filPais = '';
    $filGuia = '';
}else{
        $filProveedor = $_GET['filProveedor'];
        $filEstatus = $_GET['filEstatus'];
        $filPais = $_GET['filPaises'];
        $filGuia = $_GET['filGuia'];
    }
```

These parameters will then be used for the following function:

```
function listadoFaltantes($filProveedor, $filEstatus, $filPais, $filGuia, $registroPorPagina,$pagina)
{
    conectar();
    //$consulta="SELECT * FROM articulos, estatus, ordenes, proveedor WHERE art_id_estatus = est_id AND art_pag = '0' AND art_id_orden = ord_id AND art_id_proveedor = pro_id_clave AND art_id_estatus != 'AP' AND  art_id_estatus != 'PA' AND art_id_estatus != 'LE' AND art_id_estatus != 'PB' AND  art_id_estatus != 'ER' AND art_id_estatus != 'RE' AND art_id_estatus != 'RO' AND  art_id_estatus != 'CF' AND art_id_estatus != 'CS'  AND art_id_estatus != 'EO'";
    $consulta="SELECT * 
                FROM articulos, estatus, ordenes, proveedor 
                WHERE art_id_estatus = est_id 
                AND art_id_orden = ord_id 
                AND art_id_proveedor = pro_id_clave 
                AND art_num_guia IS NULL  ";
    
    if($filProveedor != null)
    {
        $consulta.=" AND (";
        $num = count($filProveedor);
        for($i=0; $i <= $num; $i++)
        {
            $filProveedorId = $filProveedor[$i];
            if($i == 0 && $filProveedorId != null){$consulta.="art_id_proveedor='$filProveedorId'";}
            elseif($filProveedorId != null){$consulta.=" OR art_id_proveedor='$filProveedorId'";}
        }
        $consulta.=")";
    }   
    
    if($filEstatus != null)
    {
        $consulta.=" AND (";
        $num = count($filEstatus);
        for($i=0; $i <= $num; $i++)
        {
            $filEstatusId = $filEstatus[$i];
            if($i == 0 && $filEstatusId != null){$consulta.="art_id_estatus ='$filEstatusId'";}
            elseif($filEstatusId != null){$consulta.=" OR art_id_estatus ='$filEstatusId'";}
        }
        $consulta.=")";
    }
    
    echo "<script>console.log('$filPais');</script>";
    if($filPais != null){
        $consulta.=" AND (";
        $num = count($filPais);
        for($i = 0; $i <= $num; $i++){
            $filPaisId = $filPais[$i];
            echo "<script>console.log('$filPaisId');</script>";
            if($i == 0 && $filPaisId != null){$consulta.="pro_pais ='$filPaisId'";}
            elseif($filPaisId != null){$consulta.=" OR pro_pais ='$filPaisId'";}
        }
        $consulta.=")";
    }
    
    if ($filGuia == 'notNull') $consulta.=" AND art_num_guia IS NOT NULL";
    if ($filGuia == 'null') $consulta.=" AND art_num_guia IS NULL";
    
    //filtro
    $consulta.=" ORDER BY art_id_orden ASC";

    $inicio = ($pagina-1)*$registroPorPagina;
    $consulta .= " LIMIT $inicio , $registroPorPagina";
    $tabla = mysql_query($consulta);
    return $tabla;
}
```

When the page is loaded, all the possible parameters for each section should be taken into account. However, when I first load the page nothing is being shown until I comment out the **$filPais** section of the aforementioned function. I told the function to write on the console what the value of **$filPais** is and it showed me that it had nothing, or an empty string.

Why is that? Thanks!

#### Additional info

The result of a `print_r($_GET)` is

```
Array ( 
    [filProveedor] => Array ( 
                [0] => Test 
                [1] => TEST1 
                [2] => TEST11 
                [3] => TEST12 
                [4] => TEST2 
                [5] => TEST3 
            ) 
    [filEstatus] => Array ( 
                [0] => ST 
                [1] => SC 
            ) 
    [filPaises] => Array ( 
                [0] => col 
            ) 
    [aceptar] => Aceptar 
    )
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($_GET);` and find out what those $_GET variables are actually called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%5B is '['
and %5D is ']'
```

So those $_GET variables are in fact arrays i.e.

```
$_GET['filProveedor'][];
```

as are all the others

So in this code:

```
$filProveedor = $_GET['filProveedor'];
$filEstatus = $_GET['filEstatus'];
$filPais = $_GET['filPaises'];
$filGuia = $_GET['filGuia'];
```

`$filProveedor` has captured the `$_GET['filProveedor'][]` array, so you are passing a set of arrays to your function.

Either you need to pass individual occurances to the existing function or change the function to process its parameters as arrays

#### Additional debug suggestion:

In the first line of your script do

```
<?php
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_GET,1) . '</pre>';
```

OR if you have a visibility issue write it to a file

```
<?php
file_put_contents('get_debug.txt', '<pre>' . print_r($_GET,1) . '</pre>');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$_GET['filProveedor[]'];`?

Comment: @JulioGarcia nope - PHP will automatically parse request vars ending in `[]` to being arrays rather than using the `[]` as part of the identifying name ... oddly, Perl (as cgi) doesn't require the `[]` at all IIRC and will make an array whenever it gets multiple variables with the same name ... but it's been a while.

Comment: @JulioGarcia Like I said in my first comment ___Do a print_r($_GET); and find out what those $_GET variables are actually called___ and what they look like

Comment: I tried to use `$_GET['filProveedor'][]` and the page turned blank instead. Also, this is what the `print_r($_GET)` gave me: `faltantes.php?filProveedor%5B%5D=Test&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST1&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST11&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST12&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST2&filProveedor%5B%5D=TEST3&filEstatus%5B%5D=ST&filEstatus%5B%5D=SC&filPaises%5B%5D=col&aceptar=Aceptar'`

Comment: That is not the output from a `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: ... unless there's some kind of routing thing in there which punts everything beyond `/` to `index.php` and `faltantes.php` is a complete red herring ... in which case, all bets are off :|

Comment: @JulioGarcia Are you using vanilla PHP or are you using a Framework of some kind

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry for the confusion. **print_r($_GET)** would print the output but it would hide behind the page contents. Which is why I instead used `echo "<script>console.log('$filPais');</script>";`

Comment: See last suggestion in the answer, write the `print_r()` to a file on the server

Comment: @JulioGarcia That explains that one then - that's completely different, that's just writing the URL to the JS console log. If you'd done something like `console.log('<?php print_r($_GET); ?>')` ... it would probably break horribly... but if not, it *might* give you the output @RiggsFolly is expecting in the JS console ;)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for your suggestion :) This is what the file says: `<pre>Array
(
    [filProveedor] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
            [1] => TEST1
            [2] => TEST11
            [3] => TEST12
            [4] => TEST2
            [5] => TEST3
        )

    [filEstatus] => Array
        (
            [0] => ST
            [1] => SC
        )

    [filPaises] => Array
        (
            [0] => col
        )

    [aceptar] => Aceptar
)
</pre>`

Comment: @CD001 I don't want the page to break too badly :P

Comment: @JulioGarcia I put that in your question and formatted it. It basically proves what I have been saying if you look at it

Comment: @RiggsFolly What I don't understand is that if all three of these parameters are arrays and all variables should have `[]` since they are arrays, why do they work if I take out the **$filPais**?

Comment: Looking closer, your function already treats its parameters as ARRAYS. So if `$filPais` is causing a problem look closer at the part of the code

Comment: Yes, it seems it does take it as arrays. I added a `console.log()` on the code for the function to tell me what the value of **$filPais** is and it outputs a blank line.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you so much for trying your best to help me. I have found out what the problem was. It seems I was looking at the right file on the wrong folder. I don't understand why people put the same files on different folders :(